# Take a TR and force it to become vertical (like a list) using only CSS

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have markup like this:

```
 <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
 </tr>
```

That obviously creates a horizontal table. Is is possible, using only CSS to make that table display with only 1 item on each row? The desired output is similar to a unordered list with no margin or bullet points.

Comment: Why not just, ya know, write the proper HTML notation?  A list would be a better idea IMO if you want to use CSS to style it

Comment: It is for a competition where you aren't allowed to modify the HTML and the navigation is in a series of tables.... It sucks but $3000 is worth it.

Comment: I have no workaround for the IE issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is this:

HTML as above.

CSS:

```
td { width:100%; float:left; }
```

It is surprisingly simple, yet it works really well.

The root cause of this problem is that IE says that `tr` and `td` are already `block` so using `block` has no effect. IE has no knowledge of the `table-row`, `table-cell` and `table` display modes.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this should do it:

```
tr, td { display: block; }
```

It'll probably break the table it's in though and it does seem like an odd thing to be doing.

**Update:** I can't get this (or any other technique) to work in IE8 (normal or compatibility mode). It just refuses to change the display of table cells. Very weird. Sorry, I have no workaround for this.

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea why I didn't think of that.

Comment: I think @cletus should get at least 15% for helping :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no fixes -ie's rendering of tables when anything other than default positioning is applied is very buggy. Less so in ie8, but still not right.

Comment: Okay. I found my own solution. I have posted it. It works IE7+.